# How can I match % sign in logstash conditional expression?

Tags: logstash

I would like to get help with logstash 5.4.0.

I am trying to match '%CTX_DOMAIN_USER%' sign in logstash conditionals.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals

However, none of below expression had matched.

```
if [user_name] == "\%CTX_DOMAIN_USER%" { }

if [user_name] == "%%CTX_DOMAIN_USER%%" { }

if [user_name] == '%CTX_DOMAIN_USER%' { }

if [user_name] =~ /CTX_DOMAIN_USER/ { }

if [user_name] =~ /.CTX_DOMAIN_USER./ { }
```

Is there any way to match a word that included % sign?

Comment: I do not know why your answer did not work. Are you sure the field  `user_name` was set?

Comment: I was so dumb. Actually, I have reviewed the code and field *user_name* was array . So, I changes the conditon to ”%CTX_DOMAIN_USER%” in [user_name] . Then it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [message] =~ /%CTX_DOMAIN_USER%/ {}
```

Worked for me.